# The game of life recurrent function probelm

Tags: java, function, conways-game-of-life

I have a problem with implementation of my Game of Life in Java.

In GUI I have buttons which decide of inicial state of the game (oscilator, glider etc), then using Action Listener I set the first board and show it.

Then I have a function that count neighbours of my cell and set colors of my cells.
But I have a problem when I want to repeat game n times, because I don't know how to set time interval.

At this moment I don't see every step of game, but just the last one.

Below is my ActionListener:

```
private ActionListener buttonsListener = new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            Object source = e.getSource();
            if (source == button1)area = setButton1(getBoardWidth(), getBoardHeight());
            if (source == glider) area = setGlider(getBoardWidth(), getBoardHeight());
            if (source == oscilator) area = setOscilator(getBoardWidth(), getBoardHeight());

            setBoard(area, board);

        }
    };
```

Function `setBoard()` takes array of ints with 0 and 1, and convert it to `JButton[][]` array with colors.

I tried to use Overrided method `run()` that include `startTheGame()` function, which checks neighbourhood and set array of ints. I need to do this multiple times but I can't set time intervals.

```
 @Override
    public void run() {
            startTheGame(area);
            setBoard(area, board);
    }
```

Comment: How are you displaying the board?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use this timer [schedule](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Timer.html#schedule(java.util.TimerTask,%20java.util.Date)).

So you have to define a custom [TimerTask](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TimerTask.html) like this:

```
import java.util.TimerTask;

public class UserTimerTask extends TimerTask{
    @Override
    public void run() {
       startTheGame(area);
       setBoard(area, board);
    }
}
```

And then wrapping your code like this:

```
// daemon means, background. If every task is a demon task, the VM will exit
Bolean isDaemon = false;
Timer timer = new Timer("nameOfThread",isDaemon);

TimerTask task = new UserTimerTask();

// Schedules the specified task for repeated fixed-delay execution, beginning after the specified delay
// both parameters are in milliseconds
timer.schedule(task,0,1000);
```